# Multiple records in json and array, and txt reading?

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, curl

im trying to send to my api site, the following Json with one record.
It works Ok, but I want to send more than one record, how can I do that?

Later i want to read a txt and make a json with all the records in it.

```
<?php
//API URL
$url = 'http://mysitexder.net/receiveJson.php';

//create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init($url);

//setup request to send json via POST
$data = array(
'cod' => '321',
'name' => 'Jane',
'address' => 'Route 123456'
);
$payload = json_encode(array("user" => $data));

//attach encoded JSON string to the POST fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

//set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));

//return response instead of outputting
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//execute the POST request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close cURL resource
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send a 2-dimensional array:

```
$data1 = array(
'cod' => '321',
'name' => 'Jane',
'address' => 'Route 123456'
);
$data2 = array(
'cod' => '555',
'name' => 'John',
'address' => '123 Main St'
);
$payload = json_encode(array('users' => array($data1, $data2)));
```

> Later i want to read a txt and make a json with all the records in it.

It's hard to tell what you mean by this. But you should parse the text in whatever way you want (e.g. each line is a record), create a PHP array from that, and call `json_encode()`.

Comment: Great!, yes I mean that, every line in the txt file is a record, how can I parse the line of the Txt to fill an array and then json_encode the array?

Comment: If it's a CSV file, use `fgetcsv()` to read it into arrays, collect them all into another array, then use `json_encode()` the whole thing.